# duplicate products added when importing csv files

Tags: c#, csv, import, sqlbulkcopy

I am using the code below to import the csv files onto sqlserver 2008, the issue is , its adding duplicate records onto the table , how can i check to avoid duplicate records import , below is the code which i am using , i have copied from somewhere , and have forgotten the link so cant reference it , the code works fine as it imports the data , but it doesnt checks before importing , the primary key i am using for my table is productid, below is the code, any assistance or suggestion will be appreciated:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xx;Password=xxx");
    string filepath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);//"C:\\params.csv";
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        foreach (string dc in value)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
        }

        while ( !sr.EndOfStream )
        {
            value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if(value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
        bc.DestinationTableName = "products";
        bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        con.Open();
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
        bc.Close();
        con.Close(); 

}
```

Comment: when doing SQLBulkCopy.. are the constraints or logging turned off or disabled .. sounds like you may have to come up with your own Delta Mechanism.. do you have Triggers or Primary Key Constraints setup..

Comment: no i just have a simple table with 8-9 fields , and one primary key

Comment: What in the world does ASP.NET have to do with this issue? Removed the tag and fixed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should be able to set the PK field to be the `productid`. Insert would fail automatically if it's duplicated...

You could also [sort](http://weblogs.asp.net/jcogley/archive/2003/09/15/27567.aspx) the DataTable, pass through and process the duplicated rows with some logic.

Another solution would be to add the `productid` in some sort of searchable array and check against it before adding a new row.

HTH,

Comment: how to add the productid for checking?

Comment: last variant? easiest way would be to: 1. create the row and populate it, 2. get the value corresponding to the `productid` column, 3. check if the value already exists, 4. if yes, then delete the row, otherwise add the row to the table and the value to the array

Comment: dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc)); is that for creating

Comment: that's for creating the column. this will tell you which column contains productid.
                `row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;` side of things will give you the value of productid for a record.